# Ajustar o alinhamento do dropdownlist em uma navbar Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

Não sei se estou fazendo corretamente isso, mas preciso criar um dropdownlist na minha navbar para mostrar uma lista de filiais que virão do banco de dados. O problema é que quando insiro-o, fica desalinhado verticalmente. Acredito que seja por causa de alguma classe que precisa ser informada corretamente. Alguém sabe como me ajudar?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```html
<li>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Filial Administrada</label>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <select data-plugin="selectpicker" title="Selecione uma opção" class="show-tick show-menu-arrow">
        <option>FILIAL 1</option>
        <option>FILIAL 2</option>
        <option>FILIAL 3</option>
        <option>FILIAL 4</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>

<nav class="site-navbar navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar-mega" role="navigation">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle hamburger hamburger-close navbar-toggle-left hided" data-toggle="menubar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="hamburger-bar"></span>
                </button>
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-target="#site-navbar-collapse" data-toggle="collapse">
                    <i class="icon wb-more-horizontal" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </button>
    <div class="navbar-brand navbar-brand-center site-gridmenu-toggle" data-toggle="gridmenu">
      <img class="navbar-brand-logo" src="../../assets/images/logo.png" title="Remark">
      <span class="navbar-brand-text"> My System</span>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-target="#site-navbar-search" data-toggle="collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Search</span>
                    <i class="icon wb-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </button>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-container container-fluid">
    <!-- Navbar Collapse -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-collapse-toolbar" id="site-navbar-collapse">
      <!-- Navbar Toolbar -->
      <ul class="nav navbar-toolbar">
        <li class="hidden-float" id="toggleMenubar">
          <a data-toggle="menubar" href="#" role="button">
            <i class="icon hamburger hamburger-arrow-left">
                                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle menubar</span>
                                    <span class="hamburger-bar"></span>
                                </i>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="hidden-xs" id="toggleFullscreen">
          <a class="icon icon-fullscreen" data-toggle="fullscreen" href="#" role="button">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle fullscreen</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="hidden-float">
          <a class="icon wb-search" data-toggle="collapse" href="#" data-target="#site-navbar-search" role="button">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle Search</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Filial Administrada</label>
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <select data-plugin="selectpicker" title="Selecione uma opção" class="show-tick show-menu-arrow">
                <option>FILIAL 1</option>
                <option>FILIAL 2</option>
                <option>FILIAL 3</option>
                <option>FILIAL 4</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-toolbar navbar-right navbar-toolbar-right">
      </ul>
      @await Html.PartialAsync("_LoginPartial")
      <!-- End Navbar Toolbar Right -->
    </div>
    <!-- End Navbar Collapse -->
    <!-- Site Navbar Seach -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-search-overlap" id="site-navbar-search">
      <form role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-search">
            <i class="input-search-icon wb-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="site-search" placeholder="Search...">
            <button type="button" class="input-search-close icon wb-close" data-target="#site-navbar-search" data-toggle="collapse" aria-label="Close"></button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <!-- End Site Navbar Seach -->
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Veja se este CSS resolve: `select[data-plugin='selectpicker']{
   transform: translateY(-50%);
   top: 50%;
   position: relative;
}
`

Comment: Eu inserir na tag <select>, mas não funcionou...

Comment: Jalber coloque seu CSS também. Tentei fazer um teste aqui com o Bootstrap3, mas o layout não fica nem perto do que está na sua imagem... Acredito que seja pela falta do CSS

Comment: O arquivo é um pouco grande, por isso você pode baixá-lo aqui: https://onedrive.live.com/?id=40838E65B9F8787E%21120&cid=40838E65B9F8787E

Answer (score 1):

O Bootstrap possui classes específicas para alinhamento vertical.

Ao invés de:

```html
<div class="col-md-3">
  <select data-plugin="selectpicker" title="Selecione uma opção" class="show-tick show-menu-arrow">
    <option>FILIAL 1</option>
    <option>FILIAL 2</option>
    <option>FILIAL 3</option>
    <option>FILIAL 4</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Utilize:

```html
<div class="align-middle col-md-3">
  <select data-plugin="selectpicker" title="Selecione uma opção" class="show-tick show-menu-arrow">
    <option>FILIAL 1</option>
    <option>FILIAL 2</option>
    <option>FILIAL 3</option>
    <option>FILIAL 4</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Você pode tentar ainda a classe `align-bottom`, tendo em vista que não sei como estão alinhados os outros itens de sua NavBar.

Fonte: [Alinhamento vertical](https://getbootstrap.com.br/docs/4.1/utilities/vertical-align/)